# Hive replace all row values of table, where it matches value of another table

Tags: sql, hive

Table 1:

```
name    first_name  last_name

xyz          abc          def
```

Table 2:

```
name           id   

xyz             1   
abc             2   
def             3
```

Expected Output Table:

```
name    first_name  last_name

1           2            3
```

I tried to keep case statement replacing values by joining table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
select 
case when t1.name = t2.emp_name then t2.id end as name_1,
case when t1.first_name = t3.emp_name then t3.id end as name_2,
case when t1.last_name = t4.emp_name then t4.id end as name_3
from table1 as t1

join table2 as t2
on t1.name = t2.emp_name 

join table2 as t3
on t1.first_name = t3.emp_name

join table2 as t4
on t1.last_name = t4.emp_name
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when t1.name = t2.name then t2.id end as name , 
case when t1.first_name = t2.name then t2.id end as first_name , 
case when t1.last_name = t2.name then t2.id end as last_name from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 
on t1.firat_name = t2.name or 
t1.last_name = t2.name or t1.name = t2.name
```

try it  ,
it should be working ,
we use left join and we could try to aliase the columns like this

Comment: This is not giving the correct results